# get approval from manager before sharing SP document using Microsoft flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, share

Is there any way to trigger Microsoft flow when user share SharePoint document?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is a OOB method to ask approval for sharing document in SharePoint Online using Microsoft Flow, when we create a Flow, there is no trigger or action for sharing items.

We can only set to allow/stop members to share the site and individual files and folders via site settings->site permissions->access requests settings.

Comment: If the post helps you, you can mark it as answer. Thanks for your understanding.